# A reference for the Weierstrass epsilon-delta definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, continuity

I am trying to locate **a good reference** related to the ${\varepsilon-\delta}$ definition of continuity. In particular, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_(epsilon%E2%80%93delta)_of_continuous_functions), the definition was stated respectively by Weierstrass and Jordan. However, it also mentions that, in the case of Weierstrass, the definition requires neighbors ${x \in \mathcal{X}}$ of the test point also to be a member in the domain of the function, whereas Jordan removes this requirement. I am looking for **the case of Weierstrass where he actually mentions "neighbors of every test point is also a member" requirement**: ${x \in \mathcal{X}}$. Shouldn't there be a book, publication, or some notes, even though the reference could be a text book writen by someone else who elaborates this, or some paper written by Weierstrass himself?

The ${\varepsilon-\delta}$ definition of continuity:

A function ${f:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$ is said to be continuous on its domain ${\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}}$ if for every member ${x_{0} \in \mathcal{X}}$ it holds that

\begin{align}
|x - x_{0}| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon
\hspace{10pt}...\forall\varepsilon > 0,\;
\exists\delta > 0\hspace{10pt}(1)
\end{align}

given any small number ${\varepsilon > 0}$ there exists some ${\delta > 0}$ for every neighbor ${x \in \mathcal{X}}$ of ${x_{0}}$ **within the domain** to satisfy (1).

Comment: I can't have access to this article but it may help you if you have it: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17498430.2013.831241?needAccess=true ?

Comment: @someone Your suggestion looks very promising. I am also trying to get access to it, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

@someone's reference indirectly helped me.

Nakane (2014) [1] gives a succinct overview of
the ε−δ definition of continuity, which refers to
Dugac (1973) [2] for the details. Section 4.3
in [2] is based on the handwritten script by
Hettner [3] for the Weierstrass’ lecture in 1874.
According to Dugac, the definition of continuity
on a subset in the Euclidean space appears on
page 313 and 318 in the note [3]. However, while
the note [3] is available online, it is written in
German and by hand, so it is difficult to comprehend
the full detail.

[1] M. Nakane, Did Weierstrass’s differential calculus
have a limit-avoiding character? His definition of
a limit in ε–δ style,
BSHM Bulletin:
Journal of the British Society for the History of Mathematics 29 (1) (2014)
51–59. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17498430.2013.831241

[2] P. Dugac, El ́ements d’analyse de Karl Weierstrass,
Archive for History of Exact Sciences 10 (1973) 41–174.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00343406

[3] G. Hettner, Einleitung in die Theorieen der analytischen Functionen
von Prof. Dr. Weierstass. Nach den Vorlesungen im S.S. 1874, access via
the Bielefeld University’s online library:
https://ds.ub.uni-bielefeld.de/viewer/!toc/HT005348163/1/-/